# too many celery processes running

Tags: celery, htop

I have a tornado application with a celery application initiated  like this.

`celery worker --app=pluto -l INFO -Q pluto -c 4 -Ofair --logfile=pluto-celery.log`

The application is eating lot of memory, when I do an `htops` i see a lot of celery application (around 30), most of them sleeping but consuming 0.1% memory. Why do I have so many processes, is there anything wrong with the command I am using, I tried to look, but could not find about `-c 4` part of that command. How can I find more info/debug this memory leak issue ?

Comment: -c 4 is concurrency, got there by doing celery worker --help

Comment: Why would tornado application run celery worker? Celery worker should be a separate process, completely independent from Tornado app.

Comment: sorry, i should have phrased it as "with a"